# Git: replace all commits authors without changing history

Tags: git

I want to replace all of the commits authors names and emails before pushing changes into another repository. I'll need to make more changes and push them as well with replaced authors. But at the same time i want to preserve original authors in first repo.

I have found a lot of similar questions, but all of them suggesting solutions that are rewriting history. This will make it problematic to make more commits later on.

Comment: No, you cannot do this. Changing **anything** for the old commits (other than adding or removing tags) **will** change their hash and thus the history. There's no way around that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's even possible. A commit message hash includes the author along with other parameters, so there's no way you can keep the same commit and change its author. Rewriting history is the only option. You can, however, make changes only in the second repository and not the first one.

Comment: okay, why not, i can change it in additional "mediator" repo. The problem is that even if i'm running the same author-replacement script for the same repo, hashes are different each time

Comment: @stkvtflw The hashes being different is expected. If you change a single byte of the content or metadata of a commit, you will get a completely different hash. If it 's happening run to run you should verify the date stamp is not being touched; the date is part of the metadata and changing it would also change the hashes.

Comment: @stkvtflw A commit includes the author and the committer, their emails, dates, messages, pointers to parent commits and trees (directories). I.e., names and emails are not a side information, they are essential part of every commit. Change anything — and the commit's ID changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To amplify what others have said:  The history *is* the commits.  The commits are identified by hash IDs.  The hash IDs are crypographic checksums of the commits' contents. If you change anything—even a single bit—in any commit, the checksum changes, so you have a different commit, so you have different history.

There *is* a potential light or two in all this darkness, though:

> ... all of them suggesting solutions that are rewriting history.  This will make it problematic to make more commits later on.

There are two different observations to make here:

1. Commit checksums, while cryptographically complex,<sup>1</sup> are completely deterministic.  This means that if you make the *same changes* to the *same inputs*, you get the *same results*.  You can therefore build, at any time, a table of old-to-new hash IDs as long as you have the change-rule-set and the original inputs.

   You can use this old ⟷ new mapping to compute the proper joining of the sub-graphs of disparate repositories, one that uses only "old" and one that uses any mix of old and/or new.  That is just a [small matter of programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming). :-)  Depending on how much you care about this problem, it's definitely solveable.  Just note that you must use a fully deterministic process when making your changes—e.g., you will need to keep the author and commit dates unchanged, or change them in a deterministic way.
2. There's often no need to do any of this at all, thanks to [`git notes`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html).  Rather than copying old commits to new commits, simply attach notes to the old commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>Given that SHA-1 is now [technically breakable](https://shattered.it/) given enough compute time and/or money thrown at the problem, it's no longer accurate to say "secure", hence "complex".  It's still impractical, though.